# Can not deserialize instance of QueryDto out of START_ARRAY token with Multipart

Tags: json, rest, jackson

I have two methods in Rest service:

```
@Path("judgements")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface JudgementsService {
  @POST
  @Path("get1")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  void test(Set<Query> param) throws IOException;

  @POST
  @Path("get")
  Map<Query, JudgementsForQuery> getJudgementsForQueries(
          @Multipart(value = "queries", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) Set<Query> queries,
          @Multipart(value = "regional", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) RegionalType regionalType,
          @Multipart(value = "evaluation", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) EvaluationType evaluationType) throws IOException;
```

method test() works ok, method getJudgementsForQueries() throws the exception:

```
2014-04-25 10:46:56,600 ERROR [main] r.y.q.b.e.ServerExceptionMapper - Can not deserialize instance of ru.yandex.qe.model.dto.QueryDto out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream@2e5667ed; line: 1, column: 1]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of ru.yandex.qe.model.dto.QueryDto out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream@2e5667ed; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:569) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1121) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1179) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:635) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:587) ~[jackson-jaxrs-base-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
```

Seems for some reasons json packed into multipart message isn't mapped to collection correctly...

Any help appreciated!!